# Telegram Bot / Java / Contact

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Please, help me :)

I want, that user send to Telegram bot his Contanct Info, and after that - Bot take it Contact and ask to user: "Is this your phone number?"
I can`t find and create method to decide this issue...

Thank you! Very much!

```
if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("SendContact"){
//Here user send contact when pressed button
}
// I`ve tried
if(update.getMessage().hasContact){
//recend contact to user
}
//and without if()
String phoneNum = update.getMessage().getContact().getPhoneNumber();
execute(phoneNum);
```

And how can I get this Contact and recend it to him?

Answer (score 0):

===========================

```
if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasContact()){
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            Long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId(); // chatId is the unique for everyone
            String firstName = update.getMessage().getContact().getFirstName();
            String lastName = update.getMessage().getContact().getLastName();
            String phoneNumber = update.getMessage().getContact().getPhoneNumber();

            sendMessage.setText("Is this your phone number?"+ phoneNumber);// setText() filling is mandatory
            sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);// setChatId() filling is mandatory
            try {
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Send contact button**

```
    KeyboardButton contactButton = new KeyboardButton("Send contact");
    contactButton.setRequestContact(true);

    KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
    row.add(contactButton);

    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    keyboard.add(row);

    ReplyKeyboardMarkup markup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
    markup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    markup.setResizeKeyboard(true);

    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
    sendMessage.setText("Click 'Send contact' button!");
    sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(markup);
    
    execute(sendMessage);
```

**2. Handle contact**

```
   if(update.getMessage().hasContact){
     //code
   }
```